# Impervious nature of solid matter due to quantum degeneracy pressure

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, specific-reference, pauli-exclusion-principle

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_degeneracy_pressure) the following statement is made without reference:

> Freeman Dyson showed that the imperviousness of solid matter is due to
>   quantum degeneracy pressure rather than electrostatic repulsion as had
>   been previously assumed.

Can anyone find the appropriate reference(s)?

Comment: [Terry took a pop-sci crack at the issue](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/23821/520) on a earlier question. Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1077/520 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia to the rescue!

> FJ Dyson and A Lenard: Stability of Matter, Parts I and II (J. Math. Phys., 8, 423-434 
>   (1967); J. Math. Phys., 9, 698-711 (1968) ); FJ Dyson: Ground-State Energy of a Finite 
>   System of Charged Particles (J.Math.Phys. 8, 1538-1545 (1967) )

I found the reference in ref 6 of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle

Comment: Thanks John. I should've browsed around a bit more on Wikipedia myself. I think I'll add these references from the Pauli exclusion principle page to the electron degeneracy pressure page.