# How to calculate the weight in en elevator going upwards / downwards?

Tags: gravity

When the scale shows higher digits in the elevator, how do I calculate the real weight?

Comment: The scale doesn't show an increase/decrease of weight in an elevator unless it is accelerating.

Comment: that s what I meant

Comment: Duplicate of [Accelerating an elevator](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59652/accelerating-an-elevator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the scale in the elevator reads is the *normal force*. From Newton's second law, we know that $F_{\text{net}} = ma$ where $m$ is mass and $a$ is acceleration. There are only two forces on the person, the force of gravity down (equal to $mg$) and the normal force up (which I will call $F_N$). Newton's second law then yields

$$ ma = F_{N} - mg $$

AKA

$$F_{N} = m(g+a)$$

Remember $F_N$ is what the scale reads. If the elevator accelerates up ($a>0$), the reading of the scale ($F_N$) is higher than the person's weight. If the elevator accelerates down ($a<0$), the reading of the scale ($F_N$) is lower than the person's weight. If the elevator is at rest or moving at a constant velocity, the scale reads the same as the person's actual weight.