# Can an object move without physical contact?

Tags: forces, energy, condensed-matter

Does an object necessarily needs physical contact in order to move, because as far as I can guess.. energy doesn't have to be contained in matter in order to work, just like heat works in distance.

The kinetic energy is not the only force that can make the object move.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but wouldn't gravity be an example of an object moving without contact with another object?

Comment: I was thinking the same, although it produces a pull force and it is a force field, which is constraining per se.

Comment: Lots of forces don't require *"physical contact"*. It's a fairly meaningless term.

Comment: An object can move uniformly in a line by [inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia) without any force being applied, forces are needed only for acceleration. If you consider force fields to be "objects" then  all forces come from "objects" in "physical contact" with them, modern physics does not admit action at a distance (as gravity was once thought to be). However,  [energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy), kinetic in particular, is not a force.

Comment: Define "physical contact", cf. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23797/2451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gravity and the electromagnetic field are good examples.
Earth orbits around the Sun without any physical contact, a bit of physical contact with the Sun could make a disaster ... .
Or in a magnetic field, any charged particle depending on its charge is pushed or pulled by the magnetic field.
Take two magnets and draw them near each other, you should feel the force between them with your hand.

Comment: Two magnets though. In order to push an object with a magnet, the object must be positively charged right?

Comment: @Edenia with a magnet force = qv∧B where q value of charge, v is velocity and B is magnetic field, object must move to  feel the force from magnet, as formula show force is always perpendicular to v and b , but in an electric field ,positive charge pull from positive field and attract to negative field

Answer (score 9):

Physical contact is mainly a *human illusion* anyway.

Suppose your hand pushes a pint of beer across a table. Both hand and glass are made up of atoms/ions/molecules, all of which are nuclei surrounded by electron clouds. These electrons in the glass and the hand repel each other. In reality hand and glass never really touch each other. Actual 'contact' would require the *Coulombic potential energy* to reach $+\infty$.

It just feels that way because we experience the net force between the objects, mediated through the *real* electronic repulsion between hand and pint glass.

Answer (score 4):

Two objects can never really "touch" See this here [What does it mean for two objects to "touch"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23797/what-does-it-mean-for-two-objects-to-touch).  Also objects can move around with gravity or electromagnetism without physical contact (two magnets can attract and repel without any physical contact and objects gravitate toward each other without physical contact).